# Is causative form appropriate in the following usage (悪事に加担させるようそそのかす)?

Tags: meaning, causation

The following is an example sentence from "Tanaka Corpus" used in many free dictionaries (for example [down below](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%8A%A0%E6%8B%85%E8%80%85)).

> 彼は罪のない若者を悪事に加担させるようそそのかしていた。
>   He was egging an innocent young man on to join him in his crooked deal.

そそのかす is "to tempt"

加担する is generally defined as "participation" and I assume it should be the "young man" who participates.

Why then is causative form 加担させる used in this example along with よう?

Is it a mistake, or do any of these expression have a different meaning?

Would 彼は罪のない若者を悪事に加担するようそそのかしていた。  be incorrect?

---

<sup>Alternatively maybe it's 悪事に加担させる which takes direct object 若者を, is it really something that one can tempt someone else to? A tempts the young man B to let himA involve himB"?</sup>

Comment: Is there really no に following よう?  It seems a weird construct without it.  Obviously it's not in the example you linked, but it seems there should be one.

Comment: @A.Ellett I think に is optional there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - 彼は罪のない若者を悪事に加担させるよう(に)そそのかしていた。
> - 彼は罪のない若者を悪事に加担するよう(に)そそのかしていた。

I think these two sentences are equally natural, and are semantically the same.

Many verbs such as たくらむ, 計画する, 準備する do not have causative meanings. In such cases, you always need the saseru-form to express the intended meaning.

- ○ 彼は罪のない若者**を**悪事に加担させるよう計画していた。
- × 彼は罪のない若者**を**悪事に加担するよう計画していた。

For some "intrinsically causative" verbs, such as お願いする, 依頼する, 命令する, 命ずる, you should not use the saseru-form. These verbs are used in the form of `～に～するよう～する`. Combining these verbs and the saseru-form will result in awkward sentences (except in the case you really need a double-causative construction, e.g., "to order him to make her do something")

- × 彼は罪のない若者**に**悪事に加担させるよう命じていた。
- ○ 彼は罪のない若者**に**悪事に加担するよう命じていた。

A few verbs like そそのかす, 誘導する, 促す, 誘惑する, 仕向ける and 吹き込む are tricky ones, I would say. These verbs resemble causative verbs above, but they do not express direct causation. The nuance of these verbs are something indirect, like "to induce someone to do something *voluntarily* (by informing, giving an advice, giving an opportunity, etc)" In this case, I feel you can safely use the saseru-form, and it does not change the meaning of the sentence.

- ○ 彼は罪のない若者{**に/を**}悪事に加担させるよう促していた。
- ○ 彼は罪のない若者{**が/を**}悪事に加担するよう促していた。

Similar examples:

- 株を買うよう誘導する記事 ≒
  株を買わせるよう誘導する記事
- 秘密を漏洩するようそそのかす行為 ≒
  秘密を漏洩させるようそそのかす行為 <sub>([この公的文書](http://www.meti.go.jp/policy/economy/chizai/chiteki/pdf/08asia/01houseido.pdf)にあった例)</sub>
- 彼の方からごめんなさいと言うよう仕向ける ≒
  彼の方からごめんなさいと言わせるよう仕向ける
- [Examples of 仕向ける](http://yourei.jp/%E4%BB%95%E5%90%91%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B) on yourei.jp

Comment: I would like language to work like in [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/52163/11104), but the examples show I have to accept it as it is. Although, I'm not quite convinced お願いする is "more causative" than 促す, if anything I would guess the opposite - especially, as the verbs you listed as tricky ones can take the person as a direct object.

Comment: @macraf Hmm, I somehow feel お願いする is like "please do it" and 促す is more like "why don't you do it" :-) Anyway, this example may be understood as "He tempted young men in the manner of making them join..."

Comment: Interesting... For example, in a 上司 部下 relation, would you commonly use お願いする by the person higher in hierarchy to the lower, and 促す from the lower to the higher position? Or wouldn't the verbs be more appropriate in the opposite way (then 促す coming from the higher position have a more compelling feeling to it)?

Comment: No I don't think so. Both お願いする and 促す are safely used from 上司 to 部下 or from 部下 to 上司. Oh, jisho.org says 促す is "to urge", but
 促す is not a compelling action. I feel it's closer to "to encourage" or "to induce."

Comment: I'm rather surprised it's not compelling given http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/促す

Comment: @macraf I don't think these are good synonyms except for 動機づける, 速める and 促進する. I agree with [this article](http://whatimi.blog135.fc2.com/blog-entry-289.html).

Answer (score 1):

> 彼は罪のない若者を悪事に加担させるようそそのかしていた。
> He was egging an innocent young man on to join him in his crooked deal.

結論から言いますと、日本語の間違いです。
「彼は罪のない若者を悪事に加担**する**ようそそのかしていた。」が正しい日本語です。
Let me get straight to the point, the given sentence in Japanese is incorrect.
It should have been written as:
彼は罪のない若者を悪事に加担**する**ようそそのかしていた.

間違いである理由を説明します。
ＯＰが引用した英訳の後半にhimとhisがありますが、これが誰を指すか不明確なので以下のようにします。

1. A was egging B on to join B in A's crooked deal.
2. A was egging B on to join A in B's crooked deal.

引用文に、「罪のない若者 an innocent young man」と「悪事 crooked deal」がありますが、論理的に 2 ではないことが分かります。
従って、登場人物がAとBだけなら、1 が正解となります。
その場合は、日本語は私が上で示したように、「加担**させる**ようそそのかしていた」は「加担**する**ようそそのかしていた」とするべきです。

論理的に考えれば間違いと分かりますが、このように少し込み入った内容の文では、日本人でもこの文を読んで間違いと気づかず、かつ私が示した「正しい日本語」のように解釈することは普通におきます。丁寧に日本語を解釈しているＯＰだからこそ変だと感じたのだと思います。

なお、最初に示された「間違いの日本語」とされた文を正しいと解釈する方法はあります。
それは、登場人物を２人ではなく３人にする案です。英語で示すと次のようになります。

3. A was egging B on to join C in A's crooked deal.
4. A was egging C on to join B in A's crooked deal.

この英文に対応する日本語は少し修正して次のようになります。
「３．彼は罪のない若者をそそのかして**若者の友達を**（彼の）悪事に加担させるようしていた。」
「４．彼は**誰かを**そそのかして、罪のない若者を（彼の）悪事に加担させるようしていた。」

---

### EDIT

登場人物を２人ではなく３人にする案を書いて気づきましたが、登場人物が２人のままでも、日本語を次のように変更すれば意味を成します。

（正）５.「彼は罪のない若者をそそのかして（彼の）悪事に加担させるようしていた。」

（誤）６.「彼は罪のない若者を（彼の）悪事に加担させるようそそのかしていた。」

５と６とは似ていますが、５は正しく、６は間違いです。
確かに６を読んで５だと思い、間違いないと日本人でも判断しそうです。

---

## EDTI 2

正しい日本語を知っていただくために説明します。
この説明で前の私の説明と矛盾{むじゅん}があれば、この説明の方が正しいとご理解ください。

１が与えられた日本語の文章です。１から少しずつ文言｛もんごん｝を変更して６まで来ました。
１と６とでは、文言は違っても文法的には同じです。
**６の文章は一見｛いっけん｝日本語として問題ないようですが、実は間違っています**。言い換えますと、１も同じように間違っています。
６を正しい日本語に修正すると、７、８あるは９になります。
７と８は少し違いますが、日本語としては両方とも正しいです。
９は第三者である「彼女のご主人」が登場｛とうじょう｝しますが、文法的には１の文法[構造]{こうぞう}がそのまま使われております。
１０－１２は７－９とそれぞれ同じ文法構造を持っていますが、元の１と同じ文言を使っております。

結論として、１は間違いですが、１０、１１、１２のようにすれば正しい文章になります。

1. 彼は罪のない若者を悪事に加担させるようそそのかしていた。
2. 彼は<del>罪のない</del>若者を悪事に加担させるようそそのかしていた。
3. 彼は若者を「会に」参加させるようそそのかしていた。
4. 彼は若者を会に参加させるよう「説得していた」。
5. 彼は「彼女を」会に参加させるよう説得していた。
6. 彼は彼女を「同窓会に」参加させるよう説得していた。

> 7. 彼は彼女を同窓会に参加「するよう」説得していた。
> 8. 彼は彼女「に」同窓会に参加「するよう」説得していた。
> 9. 彼は彼女を同窓会に参加させるよう「彼女のご主人を」説得していた。

10. 彼は罪のない若者を悪事に加担「するよう」そそのかしていた。
11. 彼は罪のない若者「に」悪事に加担「するよう」そそのかしていた。
12. 彼は罪のない若者を悪事に加担させるよう「Ｃさんを」そそのかしていた。

Comment: As I mentioned under the [other answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/52167/11104), I think the language should work like you explained (and that was also my point of confusion), so although I would really like to accept this answer, the real-world examples made the other answer slightly more educational. Thank you.

Comment: 確かにEDIT 2の6は不自然だと思いますが、そもそも「そそのかす」と「説得する」が全く同じ用法のはずという前提が間違っていませんか。「仕向ける」には[明確に「～させるよう仕向ける」という用法もあります](http://yourei.jp/%E4%BB%95%E5%90%91%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B)が、「そそのかす」がそれと同類であるという可能性は考えましたか。

Comment: 話を逸らしてるつもりは全くありません。「6と1は同じ構造で、6が変だから1も変だ」という議論は、そもそも用法が異なる動詞とすり替えた時点で成り立たなくなります。「第三者を登場させない(二重使役にしない)」「語順を大きく入れ替えない」の条件の元で、「～させるよう～する」と言えるのはどういう場合なのか、正しい日本語を知らない私に簡潔に説明してくださいませんか。

Comment: @naruto: 「6と1は同じ構造で、6が変だから1も変だ」は分かりやすくするために使いましたが例えのすり替えだというご指摘は認めます。用例.jpで「よう（に）そそのかす」と「よう（に）仕向ける」を拝見させていただきました。「～させるよう（に）そそのかす/仕向ける」も確かにありますが、「～するよう（に）そそのかす/仕向ける」の方がかなり多いように思いました。その前に「Ｂ **を** ～ようそそのかす/仕向ける」は少なく「Ｂ **に** ～ようそそのかす/仕向ける」が多いことも気づきました。結局「Ｂを～させるよう（に）そそのかす/仕向ける」という用法はかなり少数派です。次に何故これが「Ｂに～するよう（に）そそのかす/仕向ける」という意味だと理解できるかについて考えてみます。１つ目は、文脈的にそれ以外が解釈できないからです。２つ目は、人間はそれほど賢くないので、全体として「他人に～させる」という意味合いの２重構造の文に対して、論理的におかしいことに気づかずにフライングしてしまうのだとおもいます。最後は不確かで申し訳ありませんが、「彼がいると報告した」と言う意味で書かれた「彼がいたと報告した」という文を見て、状況的に判断して是とすることは普通にあるように思いますがどうですか。私はＯＰの文を見て瞬間におかしいと感じましたが、これは感性の問題ですからこれ以上の議論はやめませんか。

Comment: はい、「多数派ではないけどこういう文は時々あり、動詞によって受容度は異なり、人によってはおかしいと思う人もいる」くらいでいいのかな、と思います。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

若者 is the object of そそのかす.  The basic sentence is

> 彼は若者をそそのかしていた。
>   He tempted the young man.

There are several examples in my dictionary of using そそのかす and for the one being tempted, the action they will take is always expressed using the causative.  I think there is a bit of logic to this.  彼 is getting 若者 to do something.  Being *tempted* is a bit like having someone *compel (force)* you to do something.  In such a situation, Japanese will use the causative.  Hence

> 悪事に加担する

would not be correct.  Rather it should be

> 悪事に加担させる

I think another way to think about this is there are two things happening: (1) being successfully tempted and (2) thus being made to do something.  So another way to write this sentence, that can perhaps make sense of this point of grammar is,

> 罪のない若者は、彼がそそのかして悪事に加担させた。

Finally, usually when using verb of commanding or compelling the action that is being compelled is usually followed not by a bare よう but by ように.  So, if there is an error, it's in the omission of this に.  But, maybe a native speaker should chime in on this particular point or grammar.